# Matlab script call from command line first calls startup?

Tags: matlab

I have a startup Matlab script  ***startup.m*** under

> C:\SVN\myscripts\StartupScript

The script sets up paths and does some subsequent script calling successfully.
However, i created another file ***callMat.m*** in the same folder that just displays some data. When i run it from Matlab GUI, it works fine.
Howeever, calling it from cmd.exe,like below:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -r "callMat"
```

I found that it opens Matlab command line and then 
it **first executes *startup.m* and then *callMat.m*** .
Is this expected behavior, and if yes Why?

Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. MATLAB executes `startup.m` when it starts up, whether it's started in the usual way, or whether it's started from the command line with `-r` and a command.

Answer (score 0):

`startup.m` on your Matlab `path` is executed on startup.

I can find no description on the [Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) suggesting that command line starting is any different.

In conclusion, it seems very likely this is expected behaviour. The documentation page [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html#brlkmbe-1) gives some suggestions as to the different places to put different options. In particular, it suggests that you:

> Use startup.m to modify the default search path, predefine variables
>   in your workspace, or define defaults for graphics objects.